# $watch vs $State.resolve of a DYNAMIC UI-Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a reusable ***dynamic table directive***:

**Directive:**

```
    <div dynamic-table schema="ThisTableSchema" datasource="someDatasource"></div>
```

The directive gets the schema for each respective table easily enough by just plugging in a hard-coded attr string, for that particular table, into an $http API string in the directive itself.

---

**Datasource:**

The datasource is quite another matter; it needs to ***come from each respective table's controller*** and thus causes a timing issue with the directive firing before the datasource is acquired by the table's controller.

Currently, my directive has a **$watch method**, and this solves the timing issue.

```
     $scope.$watch('datasource', function(newValue, oldValue){
                if(angular.isDefined(newValue)){
                    $scope.docs = newValue
                }
            });
```

I understand the alternative to the **$watch** method, if there is a performance concern, would be the **$state's resolve** method.

---

**$State: ( is dynamic --- derives from db --- uses $ocLazyLoad -- not in app.config)**

$State is dynamic and instantiated in app.run, **I cannot hard-code a resolve method** in my app.config for those states that require table data for the above directive. Nothwithstanding the resolve issue, the dynamic state works.

I have found **ABSOLUTELY ZERO** information on the Internet on how to handle a dynamic ui-router's resolve method (in lieu of using a $watch method).

Despite my best efforts, I have been unsuccessful in utilizing dynamic $state resolves.

---

**Concerned about $watch method:**

I am concerned about the $watch method. Most of my pages contain a dynamic table and so that directive will be on many pages.

**___________________________________________________________________________**

**Here are my questions:**

1. While there are many views with the above directive, only one visible view at a time has it. Does that lessen the performance concern?
2. If I am indeed exposing myself to a performance issue, how would one handle a resolve method when one's ui-router is dynamic?

   ```
      app.run(){
       ....
           MenuSvc.all().success(function (states) {
           angular.forEach(states, function (state) {

           //THIS DOES NOT WORK:
           state.resolve =  {
                'myResolveAlias': ['A_Particular_Tables_Svc',
                     function (A_Particular_Tables_Svc) {
                         return A_Particular_Tables_Svc.all();
                     }
                 ]


          // $stateProviderRef is a global variable 
          // instantiated in app.config, ie
          //  $stateProviderRef = $stateProvider
          $stateProviderRef.state(state.name, state);
     }
    }
   }
   ```

Comment: Not trying to rock your boat but possible other solutions, aside from using a watch or resolve are: to broadcast an event from the controller scope when your data is available so you can pick that up in your directive _or_ you could just pass the promise to the directive and handle the callback in the directive itself.

Comment: I appreciate that, but it would be nice to keep the controller as lean as possible and handle everything in the ui-router.

Comment: iH8, the app is too big to spin my wheels on this issue. I tried the broadcast method and it works. If it reduces performance issues, I will resign myself to a few extra lines of code in each controller. But, it would have been sweeter to handle this in the ui-router.

Comment: You want me to make this into an answer? It's kind of offtopic. It's surely better than using a $watch since the resolve won't work. I'm guessing passing the promise would be even cleaner in your controller.

Comment: Go for it man, no such thing as too much info and if it looks good and works, I will gladly give you the points.

Comment: Will do when i've got some more time on my hands. I just thought i'de mention the other options that came to mind when i saw your question.

Comment: Well, that's OK. $broadcast worked, so if I find no lags in performance I am happy. I appreciate your help as is.